# Remove Duplicate Objects From NSMutableArray object property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have one NSObject with properties as following

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * destinationid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * destinationname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * assetid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * assetname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * assetdescription;
```

Here, I save this in NSMutableArray.

The data which I get from server contains same DestinationName, but different other properties.

I want to check, if same name of Object is already added to NSMutableArray, don't add it again.

I tried to user ***innner loops*** but no use :(

Thanks

Comment: can you say what happened with innerloops .please show your code

Comment: I was unable to create logic for it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
NSArray *originalArray = ... // original array of objects with duplicates
NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableSet *names = [NSMutableSet set];
for (id obj in originalArray) {
    NSString *destinationName = [obj destinationname];
    if (![names containsObject:destinationName]) {
        [uniqueArray addObject:obj];
        [names addObject:destinationName];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create a new array that only contains the destination names from your other array, and check if the name from your server is contained there:

```
NSArray *names = [self.mut valueForKey:@"destinationname"];
    if (![names containsObject:destName]) {
        [self.mut addObject:newObjectFromServer];
    }
```

mut is the name of my mutable array, and destName is the destination name in the object your getting from the server.

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the job:

```
BOOL contains(id object, NSMutableArray *array)
{
    for (id array in yourArray)
        if ([object.destinationname isEqualToString:yourObject.destinationname])
            return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Usage example:

```
if (!contains(object, array))
    [array addObject:object];
```